# C# Pick Utility Type

Tags: c#, typescript, types

In Typescript, there is a [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) Utility Type. Is it possible to do the same in C#? For example:

```
public class SomeClassA {
    public string SomePropA { get; set; }
    public string SomePropB { get; set; }
    public string SomePropC { get; set; }
}

public class SomeClassB Pick<SomeClassA, SomePropA, SomePropB> {
}
```

Comment: c# does not have an equivalent.

Comment: I *suppose* you could make this happen using C#9's Source Generators, maybe, but I don't know enough about them.  I think they're still in preview.

Comment: Yeah my ViewModel (and DTO) classes are a mess of inheritance and splitting classes because you cant do this. But to be honest...who cares...the client certainly doesn't....